# How would i tell if I am on a certain website with Python using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, if-statement, web

So i'm trying to find a way in python using selenium to tell if i am on a certain website. So like, if I am on https://www.google.com/ , then do something, else do something else

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note it is always best to include a code sample with your questions. This makes it easier for future searchers to find, as well as gives those providing answers more to work with to help you find what you want. (i.e. posting code -> win-win)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on @supputuri's answer, there is a method on your browser object that returns the current URL that selenium is viewing of `.current_url`. You can put it into a logic block like:

```
if driver.current_url == 'https://www.google.com/':
    pass # your logic for when the browser is on google would go here
else:
    pass # your logic for when the browser is on any other site goes here
```

Although I think a cleaner and more robust way would be to use a substring like:

```
if "google" in driver.current_url:
    print("we're on google")
else:
    print(driver.current_url) # print the current URL otherwise
```

I think this is superior because say you use the `'https://www.google.com/'` test, a URL of `https://www.google.com/search?q=stack+overflow&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS819US819&oq=stack+overflow&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3j69i65j0.2927j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8` would get passed into the `else` block as if you are not on google because it isn't an *exact* match, whereas my second block of code would still see that `google` is in the URL and respond accordingly. The downside is a URL such as `https://search.yahoo.com/search?p=www.google.com` will trigger the logic. To eliminate this and only get URLs that ***start*** with google it would be best to use:

```
if driver.current_url.startswith('https://www.google.com'):
    print("we're on google")
else:
    print(driver.current_url) # print the current URL otherwise
```

Comment: Not against the approach but just want to let the OP know the edge case where the 2nd approach might fail, when you are on [page like this](https://search.yahoo.com/search?p=www.google.com&fr=yfp-t&fp=1&toggle=1&cop=mss&ei=UTF-8). If you are on AUT then mostly you can use the 2nd approach :-)

Comment: @supputuri Thanks for the comment. I originally had just "google" but then thought maybe google would show elsewhere in the URL so I changed it to "www.google.com" and neglected to mention that. I've updated it with a method that would solve that issue too! I'm realizing now just how very broad this question is and have voted to close, since there are probably many more solutions than the three I've suggested even...

Answer (score 0):

you can get the current url and then write the logic around it.

```
currentUrl = driver.current_url
if (currentUrl == 'https://www.google.com/'):
    print("your google logic goes here")
```